# module object is note callable, Siamese neural network

Tags: keras, callable, siamese-network

im trying siamese neural network with [this](https://www.katnoria.com/siamese-one-shot/) site. 
but i got error like this...

[image]

i've tried to call con_model but it still give error
i dont know much about siamese or keras or neural network. im just trying and learn. 
any body can help me to solve this code?

Comment: Please don't post images of code; see [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of that `merge`, which is probably not imported from the correct place, and is probably not recommended anymore, you can use a `Lambda` layer.

```
merged_model = keras.layers.Lambda(l1_distance)([model_output_left, model_output_right])
```

If you're using Tensorflow, the `Lambda` layers will not require an output shape. If you want an output shape for some reason, you need `keras.backend.int_shape(x[0])`. The value `x[0]` alone is not a shape!